# OpenCV, ORB Detection: How can I return the best match when compared to multiple images?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, brute-force

I am trying to get the best match from an input image when comparing this image to multiple images in an array, more specifically - trying to analyse a book cover and compare this with book covers in an array - returning the correct one. There are two ways I thought of doing this but I am not completely sure how.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

class imageCapture(object):


    def __init__(self):
        self.image = None
        self.storedImages = [r'C:\pythonImg\image1.jpg']

    def captureImage(self):
        time.sleep(2)
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        if cap.isOpened():
            ret, frame = cap.read()
            print("The image has been captured: " + str(ret))
        else:
            ret = False
        img1 = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) #this converts the colours to RGB from BGR
        self.image = img1


    def get_Matches_Orb(self): #at this point in time we are comparing it to a saved path image - eventually save the vectors
        #trainImg = cv2.imread(self.image,0)

        for image in self.storedImages:
            storedImg = cv2.imread(image,0)

            orb = cv2.ORB_create()
            kp1, des1 = orb.detectAndCompute(self.image,None) #this finds keypoints and descriptors with SIFT
            kp2, des2 = orb.detectAndCompute(storedImg,None)

            bf = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_HAMMING, crossCheck=True) #create a bfMatcher object
            matches = bf.match(des1,des2) #Match descriptors
            matches = sorted(matches, key = lambda x:x.distance) #sorts them in order of their distance - lowest distance first.

            sum = 0
            for i in matches:
                sum = sum + i.distance
            avg = sum / len(matches)
            print(avg)

            #print(avg.distance)

            img3 = cv2.drawMatches(self.image,kp1,storedImg,kp2,matches[:10],None, flags=2) #helps us to draw the matches.
            plt.imshow(img3)
            plt.show()


testobj = imageCapture()
testobj.captureImage()
testobj.get_Matches_Orb()
```

One of my ideas was to get the average distance of what DMatch returns using `DMatch.distance` and return the image with the lowest average distance - thus far I have only generated the average and tested it using different book covers. The average distance does in fact appear lower when comparing it to the correct book cover but I am wondering whether that is accurate. Which leads me to the question: is there a way of using the keypoints stored in kp1 and kp2 to compare images more accurately?

Answer (score 1):

Compare all match distance is a bad idea because there is a lot of outlier with this method .

What you need to do is to use findHomography. this will give you the transformation between your current image and your dictionary image.

Then you have to chose some parameter to validate or refuse this homography.

The easiest way (for me) is to project a box from the dictionary into your current image and try to see if the shape of the box is good enough (or not) (is area in a good range scale?, corner with allowed angle? etc..). or you can set a threshold on the number of inlier, their repartition etc...

To make something robust you will probably use several criteria

Take a look a this tutorial. they used surf keypoint but you can use orb instead. https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_homography/feature_homography.html